# Are there any Indian movies which contain breaking the fourth wall?

Tags: trope, indian-cinema, fourth-wall

India produces the second most movies after Hollywood.

So does the trope of breaking the fourth wall exist in Indian movies?

Comment: Golmaal 2 ending scene

Comment: This question is not asking for recommendations, nor is it too broad... it's asking if it exists....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Indian Bollywood movies, it is pretty common to break the fourth wall in comic scenes. Like in the movie Mard, the lead actor Amitabh Bacchan talks facing the screen. He is clearly talking to the audience.

There are some movies with Govinda and Kadar Khan where they talk to the audience. Also, in a lot of 80's movie end scenes you can find an actor asking the audience to leave to their homes.

However, the term "breaking the fourth wall" is not common in bollywood. It happens mostly in comedy movies or in other movies in comic way.

Comment: How is your last sentence supposed to be understood? The terminology of "breaking the fourth wall" is not related to science-fiction at all.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson yes its not related to sci-fi however normally it is used with sci-fi or comic world movies.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Even though you have things like soliloquies in works like Hamlet, you could argue that BTFW is *often used for comedy, dramatic irony (dark comedy), or character introspection and that is like having a science-fiction element in any given story/genre, since science fiction often explores "meta" physics. I get what Panther was trying to say, even though BTFW is not limited to any given genre.

Answer (score 1):

**"The Accidental Prime minister"**  is one such movie where the fourth wall is broken most of the times by the actor Akshay Khanna who plays the role of Sanjay Baru the narrator of the story and also on whose book the film is based. Sanjay Baru was a secretary in Dr. Manmohan Singh's regime.